# Use Greasemonkey to replace links, to images, with images?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, hyperlink, greasemonkey

I'm new to Greasemonkey and I would like to replace the links to images, with just an `<img>` tag instead.

For example, [this forums page](http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/eat-drink-man-woman-16/shocking-n-funny-gifs-2392574-print.html?pp=50) has a bunch of links like:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://url.com/pic.gif">http://url.com/pic.gif</a>
```

I want to replace these links with images like:

```
<img src="http://url.com/pic.gif">
```

I searched the net and managed to find something like [this Greasemonkey user's group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/greasemonkey-users/BxM6BQhxiEI).
But, my edited code:

```
var i, x = document.evaluate (
    '//*[@target="_blank"][@href="="]',
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null
);
for (i = 0; i < x.snapshotLength; i++)
    x.snapshotItem(i).setAttribute("href", "img src");
```

does not seem to work.

Please advise how should I go about creating this script.

Comment: You can do it exactly the way you would do with your regular html and javascript.

Comment: i'm not sure how to change it.

Comment: You need to show a little more effort. At least give us the current HTML snippet and the desired HTML snippet.  A link to the target page would be super-helpful too.

Comment: for example this page http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/eat-drink-man-woman-16/shocking-n-funny-gifs-2392574-print.html?pp=50 , it shows all hyperlink with images, i checked the source it is using e.g. <a target="_blank" href="http://www.url.com/pic.gif">http://www.url.com/pic.gif</a> . I would like to replace it to use img src instead.

Comment: i tried research from the net and manage to find something like https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/greasemonkey-users/BxM6BQhxiEI . my edited code is below which does not seems to work: var i, x = document.evaluate('//*[@target="_blank"][@href="="]', document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

for ( i=0 ; i < x.snapshotLength; i++ )
    x.snapshotItem(i).setAttribute("href", "img src");

Comment: Thanks for providing the requested information.  However, don't put it in comments -- especially code.  Edit your question to add key info and code snippets.  I have done this for you, this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replacing links to images is not too hard to do.  However, I recommend that you keep the link but display the picture inside it.  This is so you can click through if something goes wrong.  For example, [that sample page you gave](http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/eat-drink-man-woman-16/shocking-n-funny-gifs-2392574-print.html?pp=50) has most of the linked images on a dead site.

Other linked images only *look* like they point to images or might be blocked for "hot linking".

To make the code robust and easy, we use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [waitForKeyElements](https://gist.github.com/2625891).

Here is **a complete working script** that delinks the *payload* image-links on [that sample site](http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/eat-drink-man-woman-16/shocking-n-funny-gifs-2392574-print.html?pp=50):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    _Image delinker
// @include http://forums.hardwarezone.com.sg/*
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant   GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

var imageExtensions = ["gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg"];
var imgExtRegex     = new RegExp(
    '\\.(' + imageExtensions.join ('|') + ')$', 'i'
);

/*-- Tune the CSS path, for each site, to only find links that can be
    the image links you care about.
*/
//-- For forums.hardwarezone.com.sg
waitForKeyElements ("td.page div > a", delinkImage);

function delinkImage (jNode) {
    var imgUrl  = jNode.attr ("href");

    if (imgExtRegex.test (imgUrl) ) {
        //-- Found an image link.  Replace contents.
        jNode.html (
            '<img src="' + imgUrl
            + '" class="gmDeLinked" alt="GM replaced image">'
        );
    }
}

GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    img.gmDeLinked {                            \
        border:             1px solid lime;     \
        max-width:          90vw;               \
    }                                           \
" );
```

Comment: Thanks Brock Adams, your script is awesome. I hope I can have the time to explore more useful features of greasemonkey and also learn how to write my own scripts :)

Comment: You're welcome.  Lookup jQuery and learn how to modify web pages with it; you'll be well on the way to writing scripts then.